# If I only want to use redis pubsub to create some real time client functionality, is it ok security-wise to connect to redis direct from client?

Tags: security, actionscript, redis

I'm trying to create a Flash app with some real time functionality, and would like to use Redis' pubsub functionality which is a perfect fit for what I need.

I know that connecting to a data store directly from client is almost always bad. What are the security implications of this (since I'm not an expert on Redis), and are there ways to work around them? From what I read, there is a possible exploit of doing config sets and changing the rdb file location and be able to arbitrary overwrite files. Is there anything else? (If I don't use that particular redis instance for *anything* at all, i.e. no data being stored)

I understand the alternative is to write some custom socket server program and have it act as the mediating layer for connecting to redis and issuing commands -- that's the work I'd like to avoid having to write, if possible.

** Edit **

Just learned about the rename-command configuration to disable commands. If I disable every single command on the redis instance and leave only SUBSCRIBE and PUBLISH open, would this be good enough to run on production?

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be a bad idea to connect directly your client to Redis. Redis offers an [authentication system](http://redis.io/commands/auth) for a unique user only. It expects this user to be your server app.

From my point of view, directly exposing Redis is always a bad idea. It would allow anybody to access all of your data. This is [confirmed by the Redis doc](http://redis.io/topics/security).

So you won't avoid adding or developing the server side of your app.

Comment: Thanks for the resource links. Note that I mentioned that this would be a Redis instance that I don't use for anything else at all -- no data will be stored in it. I want to use it purely for the pubsub feature. If I don't care very much about someone connecting to it and subscribing to a channel I publish to, are there any other risks?

Comment: If you don't care that people can access to all channels, not only theirs, then it could be OK. Otherwise, it's not.